# JQuery Mobile 1.4.5 Close Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, dialog

How do I close a JQuery Mobile dialog with code?

I'm using JQuery Mobile 1.4.5 and I've created a dialog with a submit button like this:

```
<div data-role="page" data-dialog="true" id="settings" data-close-btn="right">
    <!-- All content in here -->
    <input type="submit" id="btnSaveDefault" data-role="button" data-icon="check" value="Save" />
</div>
```

My button has a JavaScript function:

```
$("#btnSaveDefault").click(function() {
    // Need a close dialog function here
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated, cheers.

Comment: normally you would that with `$("#settings").dialog("close");`, but somehow i get an error when i do that with your html.

Comment: Yeah I experienced that too :/

Comment: probably because your **Dialog** is your **Page** at the same time

Comment: Yeah but that seems to be the way to make dialogs in the latest JQuery Mobile version :/  It looks a lot better this way compared to the `data-role="dialog"` method.

Comment: You might want to consider using the popup widget instead of a page set to dialog.

Comment: @ezanker Why should I consider that?

Comment: A popup sits on top of the page whereas in 1.4.x launching a dialog actually leaves the current page.  With the popup you can close it and you are right back where you left off. If you load a dialog and then go back, you go through the whole page show sequence which is probably not needed. Of course it depends on your specific use case...

Comment: Thanks, I'm ok with using the page dialog though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your dialog is a page, you could use: `$.mobile.back();` inside your click handler.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/azmjwy4z/

Comment: Just what I was looking for!  Thank you so much :)